# How to nest nodes in TikZ to multiple levels?

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw the following picture using TikZ? This requires, I guess, multiple levels of nesting of nodes. matrix nodes cannot be nested at multiple levels.

[image: A function definition with boxes]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why use TikZ at all?

(I put a `\strut` in the innermost box to make it nice and symmetric)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\[ \boxed{f = \boxed{x \to \boxed{\boxed{\strut x^2} + 2 x + 1}}} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]